# IGraph: network distance until stop node/vertex

Tags: r, nodes, igraph, social-networking

I have an `igraph` network that contains two types of nodes, one set that describes my points/nodes of interest (`NOI`) and another set that act as barriers (`B`) in my network. Now I'd like to measure the total length of all edges that are connected starting from a specific `NOI` until a barrier is approached.
Here a short example using a ring-shape in `igraph`:

```
set.seed(123)
g <- make_ring(10) %>%
  set_edge_attr("weight", value = rnorm(10,100,20))%>%
  set_vertex_attr("barrier", value = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0))%>%
  set_vertex_attr("color", value = c("green","green","red",
                                       "green","green","red",
                                       "green","green","red","green"))
```

[image]

For example when starting from my node 1  (`NOI`, green) all edges until the nodes 9 and 3 are reachable (the nodes 9 and 3 are barriers `B` and block). Thus the total connected length of edges for NOI 1 is the sum of the lengths/weights of edges 1--2,2--3,1--10 and 10--9. The same value is true for node 10 as starting node. I the end I am interested in a list/dataframe of all NOI and their total length of reachable network. How to best proceed in `R` using `igraph`? Is there a built-in function in `igraph`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible strategy. First, I set a name for each node so I will be preserved during graph transformations

```
V(g)$name = seq.int(vcount(g))
```

Now I drop all the barriers and split the graph up into separate connected nodes of interest that will all share the same length.

```
gd <- g %>% induced_subgraph(V(g)[V(g)$barrier==0]) %>% decompose()
```

Then We can write a helper function that takes a subgraph and finds all the incident edges for the nodes in the subgraph in the the original graph, extracts the weights, and sums them up

```
get_connected_length <- function(x) {
  incident_edges(g, V(g)$name %in% V(x)$name) %>% do.call("c", .) %>% unique() %>% .$weight %>% sum()
}
```

Now we apply the function to each of the subgraphs and extract the node names

```
n <- gd %>% Map(function(x) V(x)$name, .)
w <- gd %>% Map(get_connected_length, .)
```

And we can combine that data all together in a matrix

```
do.call("rbind", Map(cbind, n, w))
#      [,1]     [,2]
# [1,]    1 361.5366
# [2,]    2 361.5366
# [3,]   10 361.5366
# [4,]    4 335.1701
# [5,]    5 335.1701
# [6,]    7 318.2184
# [7,]    8 318.2184
```